# how to add column to ps cammand linux freebsd and develop it?

Tags: freebsd, ps

How can I display a new column output from the ps command in FreeBSD?

Should I change ps.c or print.c in following directory, re-build the kernel and install it?

usr/src/bin/ps

which part of code should be changed?

Comment: Er, are you asking about Linux or FreeBSD? They are not the same thing.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the option `-O`. Besides that, you may want to reformulate your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *what* you whant to display.

If the information you want can already be found in the KEYWORDS section of the [manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&sektion=1), you can use the `-O` option to display it.

Otherwise you will either hace to hack the source code, or use another utility altogether. When you decide to edit the source, I think you should start with `keyword.c`, to add a new keyword for whatever you want to display.